# About people working in 2 or more institutions?

Tags: word-choice

About people working in 2 or more institutions: which of the variants below is correct?

> those affiliated *with/to/in* two or more institutions

(My question is about using the term "affiliated", so please do not advise using e.g. "working at/in", etc.)

Comment: [This NGram usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=affiliated+with+the%2Caffiliated+to+the%2Caffiliated+in+the&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caffiliated%20with%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caffiliated%20to%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caffiliated%20in%20the%3B%2Cc0) might help you choose. Note that you can also do a wildcard NGram search for **affiliated * the**, which will show *other* possible prepositions (but ***with*** is way out front, with ***to*** a distant second). I don't think "correct" is very meaningful here.

Comment: Both 'affiliated with' and 'affiliated to' are fine, generally used for institutions and not for people working.